# Проблема с Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Прошу помочь с добавлением [**проекта**](https://github.com/AlicJ/android-auto-clicker) в Android Studio 3.2.1 , проект 2015 года , и есть подозрение, что есть нестыковки версий. Делал через *Open an existing* и *Import project*. Вылетает ошибка одна за одной. Я новичок, прошу не судить строго, спасибо. 
Перечень ошибок - действий:

> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc2 Install Build Tools 23.0.0 rc2 and sync project

Когда пробую установить, выдает ошибку:

> the following packages are not available

Comment: если есть ошибки, то покажите их нам

Comment: @iFr0z, добавил , пробывал изменить с 23.0.0 rc2 на 23.0.0 , но потом вылетает другая ошибка , пока не описываю так как незнаю правильно ли я сделал что изменил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле `build.gradle` (в папке `app`) удали строчку `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"`. А `compileSdkVersion 17` замени на ту версию, что у тебя установлена. Например, на

`compileSdkVersion 27`